# Regex multiple match in random order

Tags: python, regex

I can have such strings:

```
movie = '007: Spectre English Trailer #3 2015'
or
007: Spectre (2015) English Trailer
or
007: Spectre 2015 Trailer 2
etc.
```

Currently I have the next piece of code:

```
lang = 'english'
year = 2015
video_type = 'trailer'
num = 3 # for example '3', but can be any

my_list = []

if re.search(video_type+r'\s+((?#|№)['+str(num)+']\D)', movie, re.IGNORECASE):
    my_list.append(movie)
```

which checks if `video_type` and `num` trailer exists in the string.

How to add `lang` and `year` to regex to check if `lang`, `year`, `video_type` and `num` all together are in the string? In other words I need to check if string contains all these vars.

Somethink like:

```
if (lang in movie) and (year in movie) and (video_type in movie) and (num in movie):
    my_list.append(movie)
```

All these variables can be in random places of the string (except `video_type` and `num` as they are always close to each other and code above works ok).

Tried something like this:

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? There might be a better way.

Comment: I need to check if string contains lang, year, video_type and num

Comment: Yes I can read your code. What is the `# do something` (in plain English). Right now it sounds like the best bet is `all(field in movie.lower() for field in [lang, year, video_type, num])`

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with a single check (or if you do it's going to be hard to read/debug later). I think you'll have to create a case for each possible ordering.

Comment: Why the extended comment construct `(?#|№)` ?

Comment: @sin, because string may contain 'trailer 2', 'trailer #2', 'trailer №2'

Comment: `(?# comment here, not regex)`

Comment: @AdamSmith, would it be better to solve my problem this way -> if (re.search(video_type+r'\s+((?#|№)['+str(num)+']\D)', movie, re.IGNORECASE)) and all(field in movie.lower() for field in [lang, year]): my_list.append(movie)  ? I need regex at least for video_type+num part as shown in the examples 2 comments above

Comment: `Tried something like this:` -> ??

Comment: @sln, sorry sin, still didn't catch. Could you explain?

Comment: @TitanFighter `(?# ... )` is a comment inside a regex. You probably wanted `(?:#|№)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment indicates all you really care is that the following fields are present ANYWHERE in the string:

- `lang`
- `year`
- `video_type num` or `video_type #num` or `video_type №num`

You should use regex to detect the last one, but the others should just be a simple `in` check.

```
m = movie.casefold()  # .lower() in earlier versions before 3.3
if all([lang in m,
        year in m,
        re.search(r"{} (?:#|№)?{}(?=\D|$)".format(video_type, num), m)]):
    # do something
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if lang in m and year in m and re.search(r"{} (?:#|№)?{}(?=\D|$)".format(video_type, num), m):
```

but is massively more readable

Comment: Wow. Perfect. May I ask you to edit your code for 1 more thing which I just found, because regexp makes me crazy? '007: Spectre English Trailer #2 2015' works ok, but '007: Spectre English Trailer 2015' also works. Could you edit your code to ignore strings with more than 1 digit after 'num', so to allow re to accept strings with end-part like 'Trailer #2 2015', 'Trailer #2 (2015)', 'Trailer #2', 'Trailer #2 English', and so on but not Trailer 2015'? Thans

Comment: yeap. For now, re does not accept 'Trailer 2015' as it was asked, but also it does not accept 'Trailer 2' any more, but I need it :(

Comment: @TitanFighter Ah I didn't think about it being end of line. It should be working now